# How can a RuntimeWarning be handled when a ZeroDivisionError doesn't appear?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm writing a function using numpy and matplotlib.pyplot to generate a slope field based on some code I found in an old blog.  That code works fine, but I was trying to make a function for it.  The function takes a range for x and y, a frequency, and finally some differential equation in the form dy/dx = (some function of x and y). The differential equation is itself a function.  Of course, depending on the equation, division by zero can occur.  When it does, I get a

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

and the rest of the slope field displays in pyplot as expected, absent a value at whatever coordinate(s) caused division by zero.  Finding the actual value of the equation at those coordinates is beyond the scope of the simple function, but I would obviously like to handle such cases.

The differential equation I used to test different methods of dealing with this can be described in python as:

```
def fun3(x, y):
    return (x + y) / (x - y)
```

For this particular equation, the only point causing the issue is the point (0, 0). As such, the slope field returned by my function looks like:

[image: slope field]

No line at (0, 0), but that's not an issue.  The problem is that before the field is displayed, I get the `RuntimeWarning` described above.

The code that actually generates the field is here:

```
for j in x:
    for k in y:

        slope = diff(j, k)
        domain = np.linspace(j - 0.07, j + 0.07, 2)

        def fun(x1, y1):
            z = slope * (domain - x1) + y1
            return z

        field += plt.plot(domain, fun(j, k))
```

Where `x` and `y` are ndarrays containing the x-values and y-values, respectively, where the lines are to be drawn, including in this case (0, 0).  `field` is what is returned by the function, a list of artists added to the plot.

My first attempt at fixing the issue was to just catch the `ZeroDivisionError` within the loop, before assigning `slope`, using:

```
try:
    diff(j, k)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    continue
```

Where `diff` is the equation described by `fun3` above.  However, this failed to produce the desired result and in fact changed nothing at all about the output.  When I tried recreating this result outside of the function using something like,

```
try:
    fun3(0, 0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('oops')
```

`'oops'` is printed as expected.  What makes this different than the code inside the function that didn't work?  It ultimately does the same thing by calling `fun3` and checking for the `ZeroDivisionError`.  When the nested loops eventually reach the value (0, 0), If the `ZeroDivisionError` does not appear, how can I handle the `RuntimeWarning`?